# What is the reason for this change of reputation? Reputation tab says "-2" and "removed".

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits, reputation-tab

About an hour ago, my reputation was decreased by 2. I was curious, because I usually do not receive down-votes. However, when I got on my profile page, I was really confused. What does this "removed" mean? Also, I do not think that question is mine. The image is below:

[image]

Comment: Hopefully, someone who had something similar to this will be able to answer. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You had gotten +2 yesterday for an accepted suggested edit on "Is the following a valid proof that shows a limit does not exist?"

This post you had edited, then got deleted for some reason. As a consequence of this the +2 from the suggested edit to that post got invalidated.

You were not targeted specifically. It is an automatic consequence of how things work.

Comment: OH, now I understand! Thank you!