# No record of change of 2 rep

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I'm just curious and not particularly concerned to know that when my rep changed from 2005 to 2003, I went to check the rep tab, and there I could see no reason for that happening which is the first-of-its-kind thing for me.

<s>Any ideas?</s>

***Edit:***
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521786/combinatorial-marble-question

 As pointed out by quid, above is the reason for the change of 2.

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1837091

 for users below 10k, as MartinSleziak has shown, can check from the above link.

But still I wonder why it did not show up in the reputation tab?

---

My rep tab (Kindly focus on the "yesterday" part. No negative is present!:

[image]

Comment: It's hard to be sure, it could be the deletion of a question you edited via a suggested edit. There is a somewhat recent event of this kind and it maybe does  not register instantly.

Comment: The obligatory question: It the checkbox "show removed posts" at the bottom of your [reputation tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation) checked?

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes.

Comment: @quid if the register happens late but it does nonetheless then I will make sure to inform here. But nothing yet.

Comment: You were downvoted recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519544/mutually-exclusive-question/4519629#4519629). Is that the reason?

Comment: @ArcticChar no, that post was downvoted 2 days ago and I have received it's notification right then itself. Confirmed from the reputation tab again.

Comment: Here is a SEDE query which lists [suggested edits on deleted post](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1633018/suggested-edits-by-a-given-user-on-deleted-posts?userid=1050858) (for a given user). The database is updated once a week - maybe after the weekend (i.e., after the next update) you can check whether some new entries are shown there.

Comment: I do not understand what you say. It was displayed. I am referring to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521786/combinatorial-marble-question

Comment: Quid's theory is as good as any. I once saw in my reputation tap that I lost 2 points because a user was removed. That was a bit baffling. The best match could be that somebody had upvoted one of my posts and downvoted four for a total of +2, and those were then invalidated. But I don't get many downvotes. Go figure?

Comment: For an approved edit, a post that was removed due to the deletion of the user will result in a -2.

Comment: All I'm saying is that perhaps what @Nij or Quid says might have happened But, there is no record of it in the reputation tab. That's all. [No removed notification, no deleted notification, no user deleted notification, etc. All the entries are positive and none negative.] [None belonging to yesterday.]

Comment: Also, I can't see the post by @quid so I can't verify either, (none to blame ofc).

Comment: @InanimateBeing The post is deleted - but if you check a [link to the suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1837091), you should see it. (At least I see the suggested edit even while not logged in, so I do not think that for viewing the suggested edit review of a deleted post one needs 10k+.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you. That must be it. quid was right then. Though I wonder still why it did not show up in the reputation tab. (?!)

Comment: @quid Looking at another question here on meta (and your answer there) it seems that in that case the reputation change was displayed in the reputation tab. (Or at least it was shown to the OP - who included the screenshot.) Here is a link to that question: [What is the reason for this change of reputation? Reputation tab says "-2" and "removed".](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25137)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I too included the screenshot now. Thank you.